# Cognito Access Token + AWS API Gateway + Postman

Tags: postman, amazon-cognito

I have figured out how to use Postman's Oauth 2.0 wizard to obtain access tokens from Cognito User Pools (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53018712/633213) however, it seems that Cognito expects to receive these tokens with the word "Bearer" prepended, but Postman doesn't seem to have an option to omit this.[image]
Is it possible to use Postman's excelent support for Oauth 2.0 with Cognito + AWS API Gateway?

Comment: Pointing folks to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287506/how-do-i-integrate-amazon-cognito-login-in-postman - where this is answered in a comment pointing to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=241945 - where 'Bearer' is not required any longer