# How do i get an Amazon Cognito token in postman without need for manual steps

Tags: postman, amazon-cognito

I have an existing suite of postman tests that previously ran against REST services hosted in Azure using Azure AD for Auth. Using the token endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/token), I was able to obtain an Oauth token for an enterprise app (test app) that had deligate permissions for the application under test.

The apps have been moved to AWS and are now secured with Cognito. I have been unable to find an equivalent workflow that allows me to obtain a token without manual data being entered by the user.

The login endpoint requires me to manually enter the user name and password:
[How do i integrate amazon cognito login in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287506/how-do-i-integrate-amazon-cognito-login-in-postman)

and

I can setup an app and get an acceess token it does not give me permissions to the APIs, as I can not add the app to the user group with permissions. 
https://lobster1234.github.io/2018/05/31/server-to-server-auth-with-amazon-cognito/

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but as a reference for future viewers, I found this tool very useful and easy to integrate in CI/CD: https://github.com/nordcloud/cognitocurl

Running
`$ cognitocurl --cognitoclient CLIENT_ID --userpool USER_POOL_ID --token --username USER_NAME --password USER_PASSWORD` will print the `Authorization` token.