# Postman - how to set id token from oath2 as the variable of the environment

Tags: postman, amazon-cognito

I am getting a access token and id token from OAUTH2 using Aws Cognito following below site.

[How do i integrate amazon cognito login in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287506/how-do-i-integrate-amazon-cognito-login-in-postman)

However, I need to copy the id token and then paste it in Access Token input box in below photo.

[image]

Is there any way to store the id token got from Cognito, into my environment variable?

Comment: Do you want to automate the process of copy and paste of an access token?

Comment: Yes. Definitely

Comment: Show the api you're calling to get access token from Aws Cognito

Comment: I updated above. Please check

Comment: Perhaps, you can add the token by clicking the [Use Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtSsP.png) button, it will automatically save the token in another request(s)