# Providing an OAuth2.0 Token in Postman to talk to Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, postman, amazon-cognito

So I am using AWS Cognito as the IDP provider. I have the integration with AWS Cognito working, at least it feels that way.

I have an end-point (http://localhost/api/v1/test-me) which when I open in the browser takes me to the AWS Cognito login window, and upon successful returns the return value of the end-point ({"result": "success"}, HTTP Response Code 200) in this case.

Now, I want to test this end-point in Postman. I followed the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287506/how-do-i-integrate-amazon-cognito-login-in-postman) post to configure Postman, and I can successful create an access token. However, when testing the endpoint, with `GET http://localhost/api/v1/test-me`, I get the sign-in HTML page back in Postman. It shows Status: 200 OK, but it is clearly not letting the call go through to my end-point. I am ensuring that the token is being used with the "Bearer" header prefix.

Not sure what to do here ...[image]

Comment: can you also share the headers tab of your postman and see if authorization header is getting populated properly?

Comment: Hi Manish did you get this issue solved? if so please guide us how. I am facing the same issue